# How to refresh the page and remove delete product, when click on delete button in dropdown cart on header in opencart

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart

I try to refresh the page along with removal of cart delete data when click on delete button on drop down cart on header in opencart. I found the location on cart.tpl but I could not found the location of function when click on that button ie.

```
onclick="cart.remove('<?php echo $product['key']; ?>');
```

and I try to refresh the page using jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu .text-center .btn-xs').click(function(){
      location.reload(); 
    });

  });  
</script>
```

it refresh the page but doesn't delete the cart product.

Comment: why do you want to refresh the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the file `catalog/view/javascript/common.js`. Go to `line 200`.

Change this

```
'remove': function(key) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/remove',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'key=' + key,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#cart > button').button('loading');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#cart > button').button('reset');
            },          
            success: function(json) {
                // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
                }, 100);

                if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
                    location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
                } else {
                    $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
                }
            }
```

TO THIS

```
'remove': function(key) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/remove',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'key=' + key,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#cart > button').button('loading');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#cart > button').button('reset');
            },          
            success: function(json) {
                // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
                }, 100);

                if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
                    location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
                } else {
                    $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
                }
                location.reload();
            }
```